# How does the .Net CLR identify which .DLL is the primary (startup) DLL in a web application?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, clr

I would like to know how the CLR finds the entry point / primary DLL of a web application. How does the CLR know which DLL out of the many that exist in my `bin` directory, is *the* DLL for my website?

There is no identifying information in my `web.config` that specifies one assembly as my "primary" assembly, so how does this selection process occur?

How does this selection / initialization process work?

Answer (score 4):

That depends entirely on if you are using Web Forms, or MVC. The CLR itself does nothing to support this, it's the ASP.NET runtime and IIS that is doing all the leg work.

#### Web Form

In web forms, your .aspx and "code behind" use class inheritance to define that relationship. The @Page directive has an `Inherits` attribute defining what class the ASPX will inherit from. The ASPX itself is compiled into a class on-the-fly (or precompiled with aspnet_compiler.exe) that inherits that type.

When IIS hits an ASPX page, it passes that to the `PageHandlerFactory` either through the Integrated handler, or via the aspnet_isapi handler.

In this case, there is no "startup" DLL, it uses the DLL that the ASPX was compiled against.

#### MVC

When a request hits the ASP.NET runtime, it looks to see if there is a controller that matches the route. It then uses the [`DefaultControllerFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.defaultcontrollerfactory(v=vs.118).aspx) to try and map the route to a controller. That eventually will call `GetControllerType` to try and find the type for the Controller, which further digs into an internal type called `ControllerTypeCache`.

`ControllerTypeCache` does most of the magic. It initialized with the `EnsureInitialized`, whos job is to populate the list of all types from all assemblies that are referenced using [`BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.compilation.buildmanager.getreferencedassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx). It then crawls each assembly looking for types that match a controller, such as implementing `IController`, being public, etc.

> How does .NET know to fire up the MVC runtime

The MVC runtime is an HttpHandler. Either IIS directly passes it to the MVC handler automatically (newer versions of the framework and IIS do that) or you have to put the MVC handler in the httpHandlers section in the web.config.

In older versions of MVC you had to manually register the [`MvcHttpHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.mvchttphandler(v=vs.118).aspx). Starting in ASP.NET 4.0, a lot of the URL Routing guts were moved into the ASP.NET framework itself, so it now has this handler out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for the response - to be more specific, I'm referring to ASP.Net MVC. 

This begs the next question: How then, do we even get into the MVC runtime in the first place? I have an IIS Site pointed at my application root which contains my `bin`. How does .Net know to fire up the MVC runtime? Also, prior to any controller creation, we have a step before that where there is an entire hosting environment setup.

Comment: "How does .NET know to fire up the MVC runtime" the MVC runtime is an HttpHandler. Either IIS directly passes it to the MVC handler automatically (newer versions of the framework and IIS do that) or you have to put the MVC handler in the httpHandlers section in the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to a 'startup' DLL in an ASP.Net web app is that assembly that contains `global.asax' (if you have one). See [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb470252(v=vs.100).aspx) for details of what happens when a web app spins up.

You should also bear in mind that there can be a whole stack of `HttpModule` instances sitting on top of your web app. And your web app can add its own to the stack. The request is handed down through the stack of `HttpModules` and each of them gets the opportunity to intercept, handle, tamper with your request, etc. And once a response has been made, each module above it in the stack gets the same opportunity to monkey with the response.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to comment on your comment to @VCJones excellent explanation (this stuff usually one just *assumes* so it's a great learning moment - so kudos to your question as well!).

> How then, do we even get into the MVC runtime in the first place?

It's *my understanding* from reading this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668201(v=vs.100).aspx) that **file matching** happens first on the requested resource, then route matching (and it's handler - MVC/Web API)

---

Your question pushed me to tinker :) and fired up a new MVC application with default scaffolding, created a controller for `About`:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View();
}
```

**and** also created a physical file named `About.cshtml` in the root of the application. I fiddled with the route config so that the controller name wouldn't be part of the route - e.g. `http://localhost:123/about` (not `http://localhost:123/home/about`). So now I have

1. `About` view
2. `About.cshtml` physical file in app root (not the one in `/Views/Home/`)

Test: `http://localhost:123/About`

- First result: The MVC Controller fired. Wait, I thought it was file matching first?
- Then if I navigate to  `http://localhost:123/About.cshtml` a wierd exception is raised: `The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.cshtml' may be incorrect.` **What**?? Don't I have a ton of `cshtml` views?
- Then I saw this setting in `web.config`:

  - `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>` - what if i changed this to `true`?

Result:

Exception gone (no longer forbidden), and now I can see the behavior as described in the MSDN doc. I can't raise the `About` `view` at this point (`http://localhost:123/about`), because a file *exists* (and is the `response`), and I don't get into route matching (so the MVC handler isn't fired).

This is my *understanding* , so if I'm wrong, I'm sure someone here will point it out and another learning moment will occur :)